# write data to a smart card in StdData File

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu, smartcardio

i created a file in a smart card using this apdu command :

`String apdu = "90CD00000700000E0EA0000000";
channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(apdu)));`

the file is successefuly created , however i can't write data in that file , i tried this command :
`String apdu = "903D00003B00000000000034" + data + "00";`

but it failed with a response : sw1 91 sw2 BE (Out of boundary)

what is the problem about this file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DESFire commands use [little-endian byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little).

Your length (`000034`) gets interpreted as 3407872 bytes. You need to use `340000` to encode 52.

Try a shorter write, e.g.: `903D00000F00000000080000112233445566778800` to write '1122334455667788'...

Good luck!

EDIT>

Adjust lengths in P3 of APDU and WriteData for longer writes, e.g.:

- 903D0000**17**00000000**100000**00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF00

Note that DESFire has a frame size limit which limits the number of bytes that can be written in a single command exchange (for ISO wrapped DESFire WriteData command it is approximately 47 bytes of data). You need to perform several writes with offset (remember litte-endian encoding) or use ADDITIONAL FRAME mechanism -- see your DESFire manual (the latter is slightly faster).

Comment: thx for your answer ,  it's working well for this shorter write , but if i try a longer one i  always get 8 caracters (8 bytes) , what if i want write long data with for exemple 52 ?